# PhalconPHP config.ini item keep as string

Tags: php, string, phalcon, ini

I have an item in my config.ini that has leading zeros `item = "0001"` when I call this item in my code, Phalcon reads it as an int and removes the leading zeros which need to be preserved. I have tried casting it as a string when I call it, but Phalcon already seems to have removed the leading zeros. How can I get around this problem?

Comment: can you past your call ?

Comment: @RedKen I have tried calling it in many different ways. The problem is it is always interpreted as an integer when Phalcon reads it. The only way I seem to be able to prevent that is to put a non-integer character in front of it and then remove that string character in my code, but that's obviously a very ungraceful way of doing it!

Comment: I agree with you, there should be a better way. Did you try setting second argument to true ? 
let iniConfig = parse_ini_file(filePath, true);
?

Comment: @RedKen Sorry, it's been a while since I set this up. Where would I find that?

Comment: https://docs.phalconphp.com/hr/3.4/api/Phalcon_Config_Adapter_Ini

Comment: Hmm bit confused. I don't see anything resembling your code there. Your code looks like C so I guess you may be using Zephir. I'm just doing this in PHP. I tried adding true to the config setup in my bootstrap but that broke everything (wrong number of parameters).

Comment: Have you tried using a config.php file instead of .ini? .ini config files tend to have these issues.

Answer (score 0):

Use `INI_SCANNER_RAW` for the third param.

http://php.net/manual/en/function.parse-ini-file.php

Answer (score 0):

`Phalcon\Config\Adapter\Ini` internally uses PHP `parse_ini_file`. Phalcon passes by default the value `INI_SCANNER_RAW` as the third argument (ie the scanner mode). In any case, Phalcon **always casts** the values by using its own internal method `_cast`.

You can extend `Phalcon\Config\Adapter\Ini` and override the `_cast` method to get the desired effect :

```
<?php

class RawIntConfig extends \Phalcon\Config\Adapter\Ini
{
    protected function _cast($val)
    {
        /* If the value is numeric, we conserve it as is (ie a string).
           Otherwise we cast it normally. */
        if ( is_numeric($val) )
            return $val;

        return parent::_cast($val);
    }
}


/*
    Let's do a couple of tests.
*/

/* INI_SCANNER_RAW has no effect with Phalcon because of _cast(..).
   Note that INI_SCANNER_RAW is the default mode anyway. */
$config = new \Phalcon\Config\Adapter\Ini('config.ini', INI_SCANNER_RAW);
echo 'Using \Phalcon\Config\Adapter\Ini:<br>';
var_dump($config);

/* Expected behaviour when using parse_ini_file directly. */
$config = parse_ini_file('config.ini', true, INI_SCANNER_RAW);
echo 'Using parse_ini_file with INI_SCANNER_RAW:<br>';
var_dump($config);

/* Expected behaviour and is usable with Phalcon. */
$config = new RawIntConfig('config.ini');
echo 'Using RawIntConfig:<br>';
var_dump($config);
```

You obtain something like this :

[image: Test script output result]